# Programs in Windows 8 are pixely

Tags: windows-8

I just installed Windows 8.  For some reason many of my applications appear to be pixilated on the screen as if the program things they are running at a different resolutions then they actually are.  My graphics drivers are up to date, so what could be causing this problem?

Here's an image of what my computer looks like.
[image]

Comment: could you update the picture in your post? Take part of the screen that fits in the StackOverflow format without it being compressed. As it is now, the pixelation cannot be seen.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the cause of all the blurriness is actually the fact that Windows 8 defaults to 125% screen size, not 100%.  This means that all bitmap images are going to be pixely.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the bit depth of your display. It should be set to 24/32-bits.